# header function not working on child directory but works on parent directory

Tags: php

```
header("Location: ../mobile/index.php");
```

Header function not working on child directory file. But it works perfect when using on a parent direcory file.
can anyone know the reason ???

The problem was in the encoding of the php file. I have changed utf-8 to Unicode. Now Its working...

Comment: Define "not working".

Comment: <?php
 header("Location: index.php");
?>

Answer (score 0):

In `index.php` you need use Location like that:

```
header('Location: /file_of_root_folder.php');
```

In the child directory you use normal:

```
header('Location: ../file_of_root_folder.php');
```

The change is in the **root files**. You need put `/` before the file name.

Comment: `header('Location: index.php');` This line is not working for a single file in the same directory. but working on all other files.

Comment: If `index.php` does not exist for this single file, it's mean the `index.php` not exist in this directory.

Comment: there is a `index.php` file in the directory.

Comment: You can put all this files in a public gist please? Or just list the files in their respective folders for me?